# XSLT 1.0 extracting only the numeric numbers in block

Tags: string, xslt-1.0, numeric

I'm new to XSLT 1.0. I'm stuck at the below after many try using substring-before and substring-after.

My input string is
`txt=3000000-User from United Kingdom3000006-Do not know where user is from3000004-User only provide address`

The output I need is as below:
`<Line>3000000</Line>
 <Line>3000004</Line>
 <Line>3000006</Line>`

The code that I used is not able to know auto loop through the string for the next number

```
<Line><xsl:value-of select="substring(normalize-space(translate(translate(substring-after(txt, '-'), $uppercase, $smallcase), $smallcase, ' ')), 0, 8)"/></Line>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call a recursive template here. Assuming there is always at least one hyphen between any two numbers, try:

```
...
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="normalize-space(translate(translate(txt, translate(txt, '-0123456789', ''), ''), '-', ' '))"/>
</xsl:call-template>
...

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
    <xsl:param name="delimiter" select="' '"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($text, $delimiter)">
            <line>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </line>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, $delimiter)"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <line>
                <xsl:value-of select="$text"/>
            </line>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

---

### Edit:

Alternatively, if each number is exactly 7 digits long followed by a hyphen **and** there are no other hyphens in the text, you could make this a bit simpler:

```
... 
<xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:with-param name="text" select="txt"/>
</xsl:call-template>
...  

<xsl:template name="tokenize">
    <xsl:param name="text"/>
        <xsl:if test="contains($text, '-')">
            <xsl:param name="token" select="substring-before($text, '-')"/>
            <line>
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($token, string-length($token) - 6)"/>
            </line>
            <!-- recursive call -->
            <xsl:call-template name="tokenize">
                <xsl:with-param name="text" select="substring-after($text, '-')"/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thank you very much Michael for your reply, both you codes works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="tag">
  <xsl:variable name="NumberWithDots" select="translate(.,     'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ: ', '')"/>
  <Line>
     <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="contains($NumberWithDots, '.')">
           <xsl:value-of select="substring-before($NumberWithDots, '.')"/>
           <xsl:text>.</xsl:text>
           <xsl:value-of select="translate(substring-after($NumberWithDots, '.'), '.',     '')"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
           <xsl:value-of select="number($NumberWithDots)"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
     </xsl:choose>
  </Line>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```